# Android studio is not installed when using flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am running `flutter doctor` command. But it is saying android studio is not installed many times. I tried `flutter config --android-studio-dir=/home/khamidjon/.android`, and many more paths I tried to show but to no luck.

```
flutter doctor
```

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ android-studio-dir = /home/khamidjon/.android
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

My question is what location should be shown for PATH in `flutter config --android-studio-dir='PATH'`?

Answer (score 4):

For Android Studio installed with Flatpak, i found this config to work:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=/path/to/home/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.google.AndroidStudio/current/active/files/extra/android-studio
```

Where path/to/home is the path to your home directory.
(Ubuntu 21.10/Pop!_OS)

Comment: The location could also be `/var/lib/flatpak/app...android-studio/`. Also, Flutter doctor complains about version number when using flatpak app.

Answer (score 1):

Snap packages are installed under `/snap/appname/` with subdirectories for each new version. Try this to reslove the issue, it worked for me.

`flutter config --android-studio-dir="/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio"`

The `current` directory will make sure that it always points to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Androind Studio installed in your home directory /home/khamidjon set up PATH like this: `/home/khamidjon/android-studio/bin`

to append variable in Linux use command

```
export PATH=$PATH:/some/new/path
```

to check your PATH use

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: android studio is installed in /snap/android-studio directory. I tried this one. But it is giving me same error.

Comment: then you need to set path `/home/khamidjon/snap/android-studio/bin`

Comment: This didn't work as well. I found a another way

Comment: Post it then, so that others with the same problem could use it, and I am interested as well

Answer (score 0):

In my case snap packages can retain old versions of the program. So inside `/snap/android-studio` There were 2 versions of android studio inside directories `/snap/android-studio/99` and `/snap/android-studio/100`. So I showed one of these paths: directory `/snap/android-studio/100/android-studio` with latest version.

So I ran:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=/snap/android-studio/100/android-studio

flutter doctor
```

Result:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Where have you got `99` folder from? Seems like during installation you provided installation path to `/snap/android-studio/99/` folder, so the issue was you did not know the full installation path right?

Comment: yeah. The thing is snap lets to install multiple versions of an app. Inside 'android-studio' I had 2 directories: /99 and /100 which contained 2 android versions. I didn't pay attention to them. So, I had to show location to one of their versions I guess

Comment: @SimonSot this is autmatic folder name. It is automatically assigned by snap to control different versions. Please, read this: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/snappy-now-lets-you-install-multiple-versions-of-the-same-snap-app

Answer (score 0):

In windows

if your Android Studio install by default, you can use this command

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
```

after this command, flutter can found android studio, but the plugin can't...

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1016], locale zh-CN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.48.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

In Linux (Ubuntu)

Note: for those who are facing the problem in Ubuntu and Android Studio is installed with snap:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio"
```

Note: for those who are facing the problem in Ubuntu and Android Studio is installed with JetBrains Toolbox:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=/home/myuser/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/201.7042882
```

Where ./201.7042822 matches the current version of Android Studio installed. You'll have to check which one you have and update it in the command above.